# How do I change where my mii is from on Nintendo 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass, spotpass

How do I change where my mii is from? I try to change it and it won't let me. I put somewhere else in on accident and it won't let me change it to where I'm from.

Comment: Can you clarify? Where are you trying to change it at? I ask because I'm not seeing a place to change it in my testing.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change your location by going to:

Settings > Other Settings (Bottom Right) > Profile > Region Settings

Understand that changing your country can mess things up. You will be warned of such.

Source: Testing

Comment: I actually overlooked the Profile option three times trying to find where to change locations at. But I did find it. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: We're here to help. Glad I could be of assistance. =)